# For loop not working correctly when I introduce a variable passed from a function call

Tags: javascript

For some reason my validation function works great until I try to pass in a variable I received from a function. Currently the following works correctly, however when I uncomment `txtValue` below it doesn't work.

```
function validate(formName) {

// create an object array to hold all html nodes
var formNodes = formName.getElementsByTagName("*");
var formNodesLength = formNodes.length;
// placeholder for error codes
var error = "";
// error style
var borderStyle = "3px solid #bbd531";
var txtValue = "";

// loop and find all nodes with the attribute "validate"
for (x=0; x<formNodesLength; x++) {

    if(formNodes[x].getAttribute("data-validation")){

        nodeValue = formNodes[x].value;
        nameValue = formNodes[x].getAttribute("name");
        validateValue = formNodes[x].getAttribute("data-validation");

        if (validateValue=="text" && (nodeValue==null || nodeValue=="")) { //if text match failed
        alert(nameValue);
            /*txtValue = findLabelValue();*/
            error += /*txtValue + */" is required<br />";
            formNodes[x].style.border=borderStyle;
        }
        else if (validateValue=="email" && !nodeValue.match(/\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b/i)) { //if email match failed
            error += "email must be a valid address<br />";
            formNodes[x].style.border=borderStyle;
        }
        else if (validateValue=="phone" && !nodeValue.match(/\b[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}\b/)) { //if phone match failed
            error += "phone must be a valid<br />";
            formNodes[x].style.border=borderStyle;
        }
        else if (validateValue=="website" && !nodeValue.match(/\b[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b/i)) { //if website match failed
            error += "website must be a valid address<br />";
            formNodes[x].style.border=borderStyle;
        }
    }
}

if(error) {
    var formElement = "<div id='error-box'><strong>There was a problem with your submission</strong><br /></div>" + formName.innerHTML;
    formName.innerHTML = formElement;
    document.getElementById("error-box").innerHTML = error;
return false;
}
else {
    return true;
}


function findLabelValue() {
    var labelTagObj = formName.getElementsByTagName("label");
    var returnValue = "";

    for (x=0; x<labelTagObj.length; x++) {

        if (labelTagObj[x].getAttribute("for") == nameValue) {
            returnValue = labelTagObj[x].innerText;
            return returnValue;
        }
    }
} // End findLabelValue()


} // End validate(formName)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you're using the  global variable `x` as the counter in both `for` loops.

When you invoke the `findLabelValue()` function, it sets the global `x` to `0`, and runs the loop, which interferes with the main loop in the `validate()` function.

Use `var x` in both functions to ensure that it's not global.

Here's what you're doing, shortened to make it clearer.

```
function validate(formName) {
    // ...
    // loop using the `x` variable as a counter
    for (x=0; x<formNodesLength; x++) {
        if(formNodes[x].getAttribute("data-validation")){
            // ...
            if (validateValue=="text" && (nodeValue==null || nodeValue=="")) {
                // Invoke the other function
                txtValue = findLabelValue();
            }
            // ...
        }
    }

    // ...

    function findLabelValue() {
        // ...
        // OOPS. you've altered the same `x` being used by the other loop
        for (x=0; x<labelTagObj.length; x++) {
            // ...
        }
    } 
}
```

In both functions, `x=0` should be `var x=0`.

Comment: OMG, thank you! I've been looking at this for too long and it always ends up being something that should be so obvious.

Comment: @user1743415: Consider using a linter like http://jshint.com to check for common mistakes like this.

Comment: jshint.com is great, already cleaning things up! Thanks again :)